# Sticky load balancing on nginx reverse proxy not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup reverse proxy on existing nginx web server. I have started 3 nodejs-socket.io servers on

```
195.93.x.x:6001;
195.93.x.x:6002;
195.93.x.x:6003;
```

I can access socket.io on them separately, such as:
http://195.93.x.x:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js
But through Nginx reverse proxy I can't access socket.io servers. Get request to http://myServer.com/push/socket.io/socket.io.js returns Cannot GET /push/socket.io/socket.io.js with status 404.

Any Help is highly appreciated

Below are contents from my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myServer.com www.myServer.com;
error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log;

upstream pusher {
    ip_hash;
    server 195.93.x.x:6001;
    server 195.93.x.x:6002;
    server 195.93.x.x:6003;
         }

   location  /push {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://pusher;
           }

    location / {
     index index.php index.html;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

     #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header "domain" $http_host;
     root   /var/www/site/www;
    }

       # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/site/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Read documentation on `proxy_pass`

Comment: Sorry for the typo, actually my upstream directive is placed outside of the server block

Comment: Have you read docs? It's not so long

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem

Comment: just changed from location /push {  to location  /push/socket.io  {